# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws error while converting string to date

Tags: javascript, c#, json, json.net

JsonConvert throws an error while converting string to DateTime.

I have set date formatter to fix this issue, but still the issue exists.Could not convert string to DateTime: 14-07-2019. Path 'CartDetails[0].LineItems[0].QuoteDate', line 1, position 371.

If I set the formatter I get "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

My JSON string has the following properties

And my object has the following properties

```
public DateTime QuoteDate { get; set; }
public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }

"LastUpdatedDate": "01-01-0001"
"QuoteDate": "14-07-2019"

//var format = "dd-mm-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssK";
//var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = format};
//var myObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(checkOutBody,dateTimeConverter);
var myObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(checkOutBody);
```

I expect my object to be parsed successfully

Comment: Well shouldn't the year be at the **end** of the date format string rather than the beginning, i.e. `"dd-mm-yyyy"`?

Comment: Also, rather than `IsoDateTimeConverter` use [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatString.htm).

Comment: *I have set date formatter to fix this issue* - where did you do that? in your code example you create an instance of such a formatter but never set it where it can affect anything

Comment: @SirRufo I have set it, and commented it back as it was not working. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to use the date format you are supplying.

The following examples below will pass to the same dates

```
string varf = "{\"LastUpdatedDate\": \"01-01-0001\",\"QuoteDate\": \"07-14-2019\"}";
string varf2 = "{\"LastUpdatedDate\": \"01-01-0001\",\"QuoteDate\": \"14-07-2019\"}";


var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(varf);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(varf2, new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" });
```

In example of myObj, there is no date format so it uses `MM-dd-yyyy` but example obj uses an explict dateformat

Comment: I have already set the formatter with dd-mm-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssK settings.

Comment: look at possible date formats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings